# If statement in SDL2 is not outputting to the console

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am trying to make SDL2 output the x and y coordinates of the mouse when the left mouse button is clicked. The program ends with no error messages, however no coordinates are outputted to the console when I left click.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Math.h"
#include "RenderWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{

SDL_Event event; // get all events

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0) // error checks
        std::cout << "HEY.. SDL_Init HAS FAILED. SDL_ERROR: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    if (!(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG)))
        std::cout << "IMG_init has failed. Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    RenderWindow window("project v1.0", 1280, 720);

    SDL_Texture* backroundTexture = window.loadTexture("res/gfx/backround.png");  

    bool projRunning = true;

    while (projRunning) // quit
    {

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) // when close event occurs
        {
            int x, y;
            SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
            const SDL_MouseButtonEvent &click = event.button; // recognize mouse button events

            if (click.button == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) // detect when left mouse button is pressed
            {
                std::cout << "X = " << event.button.x << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Y = " << event.button.y << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                projRunning = false;
        }

        window.clear(); // cleanup
        window.render(backroundTexture);
        window.display();

    }

    window.cleanUp();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried taking away the curly braces in the if statement, moving parts around, but nothing has yet worked for me.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Worth noting that this line `SDL_Event event; // get all events` does not get an event, it just creates an uninitialized variable. You need to call `SDL_PollEvent` or `SDL_WaitEvent` to fill it in with the event data. You may have that in your code, but it isn't visible here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja took your advice and replaced the `SDL_Event event` with `SDL_PollEvent(&event)`. However, my problem of the coordinates not outputting when I left click is still persisting. I have edited the question to include more of the code from the program

Comment: The code checking for the button press must be inside the event loop where you have the code checking for `SDL_QUIT`,

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried running the code as it is in the updated question, but I am still not getting any output to the console.

Comment: `if (click.button == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)` is incorrect. The `button` variable in `SDL_MouseButtonEvent` is the index of the button, like 0, 1, 2. Use `if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)` instead. You can make a reference to the inner `SDL_MouseButtonEvent` after that if you like, but accessing that before you know it is a mouse button event is a problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Getting rid of the `const SDL_MouseButtonEvent &click = event.button;` line, and making the changes you suggested did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simply declaring a `SDL_Event` variable is not going to capture any events.

The reason your program does not enter the `if` block, is because `event.button` is never initialized, so the condition is always false.

To get input and other events using SDL you need to setup an event loop in your code, like so:

```
SDL_Event event;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::cout << "X = " << event.button.x << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Y = " << event.button.y << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Read more here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event